Only two keyframes currently supported with spring and inertia animations
I'm encountering an issue with keyframes while using NextUI and Framer Motion. When I trigger a fast action, such as hovering over a tooltip for less than 200ms, the rendered page breaks, and I receive an error message
Error Message
chunk-3QTN4EH6.js?v=47cbdbc1:9145 Uncaught Error: Only two keyframes currently supported with spring and inertia animations. Trying to animate scale(0.6),scale(0.61547),scale(0.65082),scale(0.69443),scale(0.73944),scale(0.78204),scale(0.82036),scale(0.85368),scale(0.88195),scale(0.90551),scale(0.92487),scale(0.94061),scale(0.95328),scale(0.9634),scale(0.97144),scale(0.97779),scale(0.98278),scale(0.98668),scale(0.98973),scale(0.99209),scale(0.99393),scale(0.99534),scale(0.99644),scale(0.99728),scale(0.99792),scale(0.99842),scale(0.99879),scale(0.99908),scale(0.9993),scale(0.99947),scale(1)
    at invariant (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:1714:13)
    at MainThreadAnimation.initPlayback (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:3006:9)
    at MainThreadAnimation.onKeyframesResolved (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:2353:36)
    at KeyframeResolver.onResolved [as onComplete] (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:2991:67)
    at KeyframeResolver.complete (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:1927:10)
    at KeyframeResolver.scheduleResolve (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:1887:12)
    at new MainThreadAnimation (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:2997:19)
    at AcceleratedAnimation.stop (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:3445:31)
    at MotionValue.stop (chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:3843:22)
    at chunk-OCSUDSUG.js?v=47cbdbc1:6796:15

Example Image Show Tooltip Without Hover

Example Image Show Tooltip Wit Hover
<div className="max-w-md:hidden relative flex justify-center items-center gap-3 text-center w-full">
              <Tooltip color="secondary" content="Details">
                <span className="text-lg text-default-500 cursor-pointer active:opacity-50">
                  <AiFillEye />
                </span>
              </Tooltip>
              <Tooltip color="secondary" content="Edit user">
                <span className="text-lg text-default-400 cursor-pointer active:opacity-50">
                  <BiEdit />
                </span>
              </Tooltip>
              <Tooltip color="danger" content="Delete user">
                <span className="text-lg text-danger cursor-pointer active:opacity-50">
                  <MdDelete />
                </span>
            </Tooltip>
</div>


Main.tsx
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.tsx';
import './index.scss';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import client from '@/graphql/apollo-client.ts';
import { NextUIProvider } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '@/redux';
import React from 'react';
// import './config/i18n.ts';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NextUIProvider>
          <App />
        </NextUIProvider>
      </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);

tailwind.config.js
const {nextui} = require("@nextui-org/react");

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

export default {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  plugins: [nextui({
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          background: "#FFFFFF", // or DEFAULT
          foreground: "#11181C", // or 50 to 900 DEFAULT
          primary: {
            //... 50 to 900
            foreground: "#FFFFFF",
            DEFAULT: "#EE4037",
          },
          default: {
            //... 50 to 900
            foreground: "#000000",
            DEFAULT: "rgba(236,236,236,0.85)",
          },
          secondary: {
            //... 50 to 900
            foreground: "#FFFFFF",
            DEFAULT: "#30445C",
          },
        },
      },
  }})],
};

Packages
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.14",
    "@graphql-codegen/near-operation-file-preset": "^2.5.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@nextui-org/react": "^2.2.10",
    "@nextui-org/theme": "^2.2.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.6",
    "flowbite": "^1.6.5",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.20",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "i18next": "^23.10.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-i18next": "^14.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "sass": "^1.74.1"


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Could you provide your Main.tsx and tailwind.config.js as code blocks please?

What version of framer motion are you using? This nexui gituhub issue seems to be the same issue you are facing.
